# Can I use a radio button selection in one part of the UI to create a heading?

Tags: r, shiny

What I would like to do is to generate a title for the panel from what the user has selected. For example, if the user selects the radio button for "z", I would like the header for the panel to say "z".

I know I can get there with a lot of conditionalPanel statements, something like conditionalPanel(condition="input.choice_crit==1",h3("First Choice")) or whatever, but it would be more elegant to use the names I have already put into the radio button choice list. And it would be easier to update if I add something else at some point.

So this code works but is obviously not dynamic. Is there a way to replace the [3] with whatever has been selected in the radio buttons so that the h3() is filled with the appropriate name from choice_crit as selected?

```
library(shiny)

choice_crit <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
names(choice_crit) <- c("z","t","\U1D6D8\U00B2","F")


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(


    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            h3(names(choice_crit[3])),
            radioButtons(inputId = "crit_select",label = "Select the statistic:",choices = choice_crit),
        ),

        # Main output
        mainPanel(
           
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? You can use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` to achive it.

```
library(shiny)

choice_crit <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
names(choice_crit) <- c("z","t","\U1D6D8\U00B2","F")


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("title"),
      radioButtons(inputId = "crit_select",
                   label = "Select the statistic:", 
                   choices = choice_crit),
    ),
    
    # Main output
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$title <- renderUI({
    h3(names(choice_crit)[as.numeric(input$crit_select)])
    #h3(names(choice_crit)[as.character(choice_crit) == input$crit_select]) # Alternative
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, you should note the documentation of the radioButtions:

> `choices`: List of values to select from (if elements of the list are named then that name rather than the value is displayed to the user). If this argument is provided, then choiceNames and choiceValues must not be provided, and vice-versa. **The values should be strings; other types (such as logicals and numbers) will be coerced to strings.**

Hence `input$crit_select` ends up being a `character` vector taking on values `"1"` through `"4"`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And thanks for thinking to add that note about choices.

Answer (score 1):

One way is you could wrap the h3 in a uiOutput, in the UI:

```
uiOutput("h3ui"),
```

in the server:

```
output$h3ui <- renderUI({
 HTML(paste0("<h3>",input$crit_select,"</h3>"))
})
```